# Getting the last two variables in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables

I am trying to make a program that shows me the data of two specific coins. What it basically does is to takes the data in an infinite "for loop" to display the info until I close the program.

And now I am trying to get the last two elements of this infinite for loop every time it runs again and make calculations with it. I know I can't just hold all the items in a list and I am not sure how to store last two's and use them every time.

```
for line in lines:
    coinsq = line.strip()
    url = priceKey + coinsq + "USDT"
    data = requests.get(url)
    datax = data.json()
    print( datax['symbol'] + " " + datax['price'])
```

Comment: you can use multithreading if you want and then do this operation.

Comment: I think For loop isn't used for infinite operations, use while loop instead.

Answer (score 4):

Store the data in a deque (from the collections module).

Initialise your deque like this:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque([], 2)
```

Now you can append to *d* as many times as you like and it will only ever have the most recent two entries.

So, for example:

```
d.append('a')
d.append('b')
d.append('c')

for e in d:
    print(e)
```

Will give the output:

```
b
c
```

Adapting your code to use this technique should be trivial.

I recommend this approach in favour of using two variables because it's easier to change if you (for some reason) decided that you want the last N values because all you need to do is change the deque constructor

Comment: When suggesting to use a module, please always include the corresponding import statement (and if it's not a default package the corresponding pip command). It's a bit more of work but always useful for peoples who read the answer.

Comment: @Xiidref I mentioned it in the text but forgot to show the actual import. My bad. Edited

Answer (score 3):

You can just use two variables that you update for each new elements, at the end you will just have the two last elements seen :

```py
pre_last = None
last = None
for line in lines:
    coinsq = line.strip()
    url = priceKey + coinsq + "USDT"
    data = requests.get(url)
    datax = data.json()
    print( datax['symbol'] + " " + datax['price'])
    pre_last = last    
    last = datax
#Do the required calculations with last and pre_last
```

(And just to be exact this isn't an infinite loop otherwise there wouldn't be a 'last' element)

Answer (score 1):

As your script does not have prior information of when the execution is going to halt, I suggest to define a queue-like structure. In each iteration, you update your last item and your previous-to-last. In that way, you just have to keep in memory two elements. I don't know how were you planning on accessing those two elements when the execution has finished, but you should be able to access that queue when the execution is over.

Sorry for not providing code, but this can be done in many ways, I supposed it was better to suggest you a way of proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable for the second-last element of the `for` loop, and **use the `datax` variable that's already defined in the loop as the last element**:

```
sec_last = None
datax = None
for line in lines:
    sec_last = datax
    coinsq = line.strip()
    url = priceKey + coinsq + "USDT"
    data = requests.get(url)
    datax = data.json()
    print( datax['symbol'] + " " + datax['price'])

print(f"Last element", datax)
print(f"Second Last element", sec_last)
```

Comment: I suppose I am the one that explained it wrong. I am trying to get the last two values of the 'datax' variable and make calculations with them every time the loop repeats.

Comment: @Dafi What do you mean `loop repeats`?